# QGIS simple downsample of a raster

Tags: qgis, raster, resampling

I'd like to downsample a DEM raster from 2m per pixel to 8m. I've tried using SAGA Multilevel B-spline interpolation (from raster) as suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260707/dsm-resolution-reduction-in-qgis), but though that results in an 8m resolution it also does some pretty drastic smoothing/blurring somewhat similar to a Gaussian filter.

I just want a simple downsample, ie take a 4 by 4 square of pixels and replace it with one pixel with their average value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Export/Save](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-new-layers-from-an-existing-layer) the image. In the export dialog window (Save Raster layer as...), you can define the new resolution. Be sure to select `Raw data` as output mode (if you don't want a rendered image for visualization purpose only as this modyfies data like bit depth):

[image]

Comment: I tried this and found that, as well as increasing the pixel size from 2 to 8 metres as expected, it also halved the bit depth from 16 Bit to 8 Bit. I can't work out why sample rate and bit depth would affect one another?

Comment: Could you provide a small sample as test data? Save as... should not change the data type. Is it right that the original DEM has Int16 as data type?

Comment: The original DEM was 32 Bit. The DEM is for use in Blender, and needs to be in UInt 16 Bit, so I used Translate to reformat. I've also used the Raster Calculator to normalise the max values to 65535 (2^16), again for the best results in Blender.  Export >Save As Rendered image then reduces the bit depth to 8 Bits. Saving as Data doesn't change the bit depth. Perhaps there's an obvious reason for this? Anyway, looks like saving as Data is the way to go.